# Append text to text hyperlink using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am working in sharepoint and using a 'content editor' to embed HTML hyperlinks on the page.

`<a href="/New%20Applications.aspx">New Applications</a>`

Now I would like to somehow get the total number of items from that list and display the number in brackets in the hyperlink, ie

[New Applications(5)](/New%20Applications.aspx)

I am familiar with using javascript on a SharePoint page and can get the value, but how would I then use javascript (if I should use JS) to add the value found to the hyperlink text?

Appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the hyperlink an ID (you would end up with `<a id="someID" href="...">New Applications<a>` you can use this code:

```
 document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML += value;
```

This will append whatever is in value to the end of "New Application"

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the number of applications in a variable, let's call it newApps, then:

```
<a href="/New%20Applications.aspx">New Applications (<script>document.write(newApps);</script>)</a>
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try your solution, since David's worked without problem, but thank you for the suggestion. :)